# What's the large version of the word "cookie"?

Tags: single-word-requests

So the word "cookie" derives from the Dutch "koekje" and points to a specific kind of small, one-person sized sweet baked good. But in Dutch the word "koekje" is the small-word version of the word "koek", which can refer to a much larger block of sweets.

For example, I made one yesterday which weighs around 1kg. It doesn't seem to be a cake or pie or any kind of pastry, as it's just a large, tough, crispy block of chocolate and grains.

So what would I call the whole thing in English?

Comment: You seem to want an English word that encompasses [halva,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halva) [fudge,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fudge) [brittle,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brittle_(food)) [Rice Krispy treats,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_Krispies_Treats) and whatever it was that you made. I don't think there is one.

Comment: Once you cut the mass up into one-person-sized pieces, in the U.S. you get [bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dessert_bar). The equivalent word in the U.K. appears to be [traybake](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/traybake), but I've never heard that in the U.S.

Comment: English doesn't work like that. I assume (I have no direct knowledge), that in Dutch "-je" works as a diminutive, like "-itto" in Spanish. English doesn't do that much... there are examples, usually stealing from Spanish or another language... But in your case, the "cookie" in English IS the diminutive, so there is no other "root" to fall back to. Honestly, it's time to get crude about it and just use you imagination. "I made this big-assed cookie! No, you don't understand, it is like a pizza-cookie!" Something like that.

Comment: Obviously you remove the diminutive and call it a *cook*. :) Or you could be of like mind with @JackRoy.

Comment: I can accept "no such thing" as an answer if that turns out to be it. But there have to be people who make things like this and describe them, right? Maybe I'll just go with "chocolate cake" or something, even though it isn't really.

Comment: It's still a cookie.  Sometimes a cheesecake, e.g., is made with a pre-baked bottom crust from a sweetened dough, and that is referred to as a cookie.

Comment: @PeterShor I'm not sure where they got that from but I've never heard *traybake* in the UK either. Had I seen that I would have assumed it to be American!

Comment: @WS2: And I assumed that *traybake* had to be British because I've never seen it in the U.S. The [Oxford Dictionary Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/tray-bake?q=tray+bake) says it's British, but I guess it's not widely used.

Comment: @PeterShor This gets more intriguing. The word is not even in my version of Oxford Dictionaries which I carry on my Kindle. There is however an entry in the mighty OED for *tray bake* as two words. It quotes three examples, none of which I have been able to find, but which all sound suspiciously American to me:
 
1980   Housecraft Oct. 236/3  

1998   Farmer's Weekly (Nexis) 17 Apr. 
2005   H. Biller et al. 101 Fuss-free Bakes 101   You can't have recipes for tray bakes and not include brownies.

Comment: The chef [Emeril](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/emeril-lagasse/giant-chocolate-chip-cookie-cake-recipe.html) seems to make something like this which he calls a *"giant cookie cake"*.

Comment: @WS2: the "101 Fuss-free Bakes" seems to be South African. One of its authors is Hilary Biller, and if you google her, you see mostly *.za* domains.

Comment: @PeterShor Ah! It may perhaps also be Australian - Southern Hemisphere English!

Comment: It's called the Cookie Monster.

Comment: Based on what I see in bakeries, the usual word for "large cookie" is just "cookie." In Australia, at least.

Comment: @WS2 "Traybake" is pretty widespread but refers at least as much to savoury concoctions as to sweet ones, for example see the [Sainsbury's magazine](https://www.sainsburysmagazine.co.uk/recipes/savoury-traybakes) (and Sainsbury's are about as British as anything gets to my mind). Having said that I think, perhaps, that a traybake is usually something one would make rather than something one would buy. I can't imagine seeing "chicken traybake" on a menu even in a Sainsbury's instore restaurant.

Comment: @BoldBen Well done! I'd not noticed it before.

Answer (score 2):

> So the word "cookie" derives from the Dutch "koekje" and points to a specific kind of small, one-person sized sweet baked good. But in Dutch the word "koekje" is the small-word version of the word "koek", which can refer to a much larger block of sweets.The culinary sense is supported by the etymology of cookie, where "Dutch koekje" is a "diminutive of koek cake" (from OED Online).

It ***really*** does not matter what your cake or cookie looked like or how big it is. "Koek" is the US origin of "cookie"

Koken = to cook. Koek - a cake, i.e. that which is cooked - koekje - the small and likeable thing that is cooked, -> cookie

OED

> Etymology: probably < Dutch koekje /ˈkuːkjə/ diminutive of koek cake: this is apparently certain for U.S.; but for Scotland historical evidence has not been found.

It is worth noting that British English uses "biscuit" - from the French "cooked twice" (hence the idea of crispness of a cookie/biscuit), and that (the consistency and method of cooking) is what distinguishes a cake from a biscuit/cookie.

For the legal difference between cakes and biscuits, the leading case on the borderline is that concerning Jaffa cakes: United Biscuits (LON/91/0160). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaffa_Cakes

Answer (score 1):

In culinary uses, depending on the region of use (deviating in Scotland, where a 'cookie' is a type of bun, and in the UK, where what is called a 'cookie' in the US is called a 'biscuit'), a cookie is a usually a type of *cake*, distinguished from other types of cake by being *small*, flat, crisp, dry and sometimes sweet. As the core definition ('a little **cake**') suggests, in cookery the correct term for an oversized 'cookie' is **cake**. The type of cake is dry, sweet, flat, and crisp, but *not small*.

The culinary sense is supported by the etymology of cookie, where "Dutch *koekje*" is a "diminutive of *koek* **cake**" (from [*OED Online*](http://oed.com/)).

> **cook·ie** also **cook·y**  (ko͝ok′ē)
>   1. A small, usually flat and crisp **cake** made from sweetened dough.

[cookie. (n.d.) *American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language*, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved December 13 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cookie .]

> **cookie** (ˈkʊkɪ) or cooky
>   1. (Cookery) US and Canadian a small flat dry sweet or plain **cake** of many varieties, baked from a dough. Also called (in Britain and certain other countries): biscuit
>   2. (Cookery) a Scot word for bun

[cookie. (n.d.) *Collins English Dictionary* – Complete and Unabridged. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003). Retrieved December 13 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cookie .]

> **cook•ie** or **cook•y** (ˈkʊk i)
>   1. a small, flat, sweetened **cake**, often round, made from stiff dough baked on a large, flat pan (cook′ie sheet`).

[cookie. (n.d.) *Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary*. (2010). Retrieved December 13 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cookie .]

> **cookie**, *n.*
>   Chiefly *Sc.* and *N. Amer*.
>   1. In Scotland the usual name for a baker's plain bun; in U.S. usually a small flat sweet **cake** (a biscuit in U.K.), but locally a name for small **cakes** of various form with or without sweetening. Also *S. Afr.* and *Canad.*

["cookie, n.". *OED Online*. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/40961?redirectedFrom=cookie (accessed December 13, 2015).]

Comment: Despite all these dictionary definitions, in the U.S. a small cake is a *cupcake*, or maybe a *petit-four*, not a cookie. Cakes and cookies generally differ greatly in composition as well as size. If I ordered a cake and got a very large cookie instead, I would not be happy. But this is additional evidence that there is no word for a large cookie in English.

Comment: @PeterShor, yes, but those aren't dry/crisp, which is another type of cake than moist/spongy. Of course, perhaps you don't admit the *technical* in cookery?

Comment: I wouldn't call *pancakes* or *crabcakes* a type of *cake*, either, so maybe my definition of *cake* is too narrow. Are there any large sweet, dry, and crisp cakes that one generally thinks of as cakes?

Comment: @PeterShor Perhaps the 'crisp' overstates the case while it speaks to my own prejudices. When a child, I fiercely resisted the notion that soft, moist cookies were really cookies at all, but they've overwhelmed the market in the US. As far as general cookie-like texture in larger cakes, though, I'll suggest some almond cakes, [Worlds Best](http://www.notderbypie.com/worlds-best-almond-cake/), and the cake of the season, fruitcake. 'Cake' in culinary use is a general term for "not of the nature of bread, made in the form of a rounded flattened mass; e.g. a fish-cake, potato-cake, pan-cake."

Comment: Amusingly, the word "cake" has been adopted into Dutch as well and points to something very different from what we'd call "koek" (specifically, things that are spongy and moist instead of crisp, like in English.)

Comment: @Erik, as you may've guessed, I'm not yet reconciled to the notion of cookies as moist, spongy things, which is what dominates the store shelves here, masquerading as cookies. I sneer at them, frankly. But as regards cake, it is the overarching culinary term. Witness the Holmes and Watson joke punchline (which I may've willfully misremembered): "look at your shoe, Watson, you'll see where the cookie went in the nighttime".

Answer (score 0):

How about ***[Pizookie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pizookie)***?

[Urban Dictionary]

The word itself is a portmanteau of pizza and cookie and pizookie is apparently a popular dessert in the US.

Comment: "Popular" is an overstatement.  You are BiscuitBoy so you have specialized knowledge.  +1 even if it sounds gross.

Comment: :D :D.. sounds gross, yet [looks](http://homemaderecipes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/cookie01.jpg) like God's wildest dream! ;)

Comment: Never heard the word before.